# Save graph and weights in file with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying save a file with the trainned model on tensorflow, I'am trying with this simple graph:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
adder_node = a + b  # + provides a shortcut for tf.add(a, b).

builder = tf.saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(".")

sess = tf.Session()
builder.add_meta_graph([tag_constants.SERVING])
builder.save()

print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: 3, b: 4.5}))
print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: [1, 3], b: [2, 4]}))
```

But it gave me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'saved_model_builder'
```

saying it doesn't exists on tensorflow module, I followed this official tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model

How can I save the trained model in tensorflow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tutorial is not updated, change `tf.saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder` into `tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder`.

Comment: aaand... they changed it again. Now it's even more confusing :) 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/save